# Multiple environments in doctrine cli

Tags: php, doctrine, command-line-interface

I'm trying to do a schema update into multiple databases, depending on the config environment used the changes will be done in a database or other.

I was trying to add an own --env parameter to the doctrine script:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine --env=dev orm:schema-tool:update --force -vvv --dump-sql
```

And inside my cli-config.php I read the argument and select my database, but after that, it fails:

```
[RuntimeException]                  
The "--env" option does not exist.  

Exception trace:
() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:213
Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->addLongOption() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:152
Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parseLongOption() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:86
Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->parse() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/symfony/console/Input/Input.php:61
Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input->bind() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:231
Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:878
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:195
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:126
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/ConsoleRunner.php:60
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php:66
include() at /var/www/consupermiso2-frontend/vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine:4


orm:schema-tool:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force]
```

How can I choose in which database I'm going to work using the cli tool?

Answer (score 1):

So lets assume that you have an application which has its own database, plus it uses a seperate database to store all of its help system data.  This help database could be shared across different installations of the application on the same server.

In Symfony its easy to specify different entity managers so you can pick and choose which one to use.  This can be done easily from command line, or from the controllers.

in your `config.yml` file, you would have something like this (the parameters for these will sit in `parameters.yml`):

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            help:
                driver:   "%database_driver2%"
                host:     "%database_host2%"
                port:     "%database_port2%"
                dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                user:     "%database_user2%"
                password: "%database_password2%"
                charset:  UTF8

orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                MainBundle: ~
        help:
            connection: customer
            mappings:
                HelpBundle: ~d
```

you will then be able to specify which database to use from command line like this:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --em=help
```

or in the controller something like this:

```
$entityManager = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('help');
```

if you need more info, have a look a the [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Comment: I'm not using Symfony, my app it's under Phalcon Framework. I have two databases, one for each environment (let's imagine different sites for different countries). So I need to specify to doctrine which database connection needs to be updated.

More specifically, my cli-config.php read a configs file (country1.yml, country2.yml) and use the specified connection params for initializing doctrine connection.

Comment: youre using the symfony console though, which is clearly stated in the error message. there will be some way of configuring it if you are just using the module, so the fundamentals of what Ive put in my answer should still apply. You need to specify a different EM for each one.

Comment: Nop. It's nothing to do with Symfony, Just doctrine.php, which launches cli-config.php.

    vendor/bin/doctrine --em=dev orm:schema-tool:update --force -vvv --dump-sql
                                 
    [RuntimeException]                 
    The "--em" option does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Oks, I've solved my self as follows:

In your config/cli-config.php file add the following code before loading your configuration file:

```
$environmentName = null;

foreach ($_SERVER['argv'] as $index => $arg) {
    $e = explode('=', $arg);
    $key = str_replace('-', '', $e[0]);

    if ('em' == $key) {
        $environmentName = $e[1];
        unset($_SERVER['argv'][$index]);
    }
}

if (empty($environmentName)) {
    throw new EmptyEnvironmentException('Try adding --em=[environment] option');
}

$environmentFilePath = PROJECT_PATH . "/config/$environmentName.yml";

if (!is_readable($environmentFilePath)) {
    throw new UnexpectedConfigFileException($environmentName);
}

$config = new PhConfig($environmentFilePath);
```

So, you must read the given property and remove it from $_SERVER['argv'], or doctrine will try to parse it throwing an exception.